# Magento - Can't add product to shopping cart after logging out

Tags: php, magento

In my Magento store (CE 1.8) (www.vossled.com), if I log out, when I click to add any product to my shopping cart, it just takes me to the shopping cart and says "No items added."

This problem is fixed if I clear the /var/cache directory, but obviously I am not going to do that every time someone logs out of the system..

Any suggestions on fixes for this?

Comment: Did you override Mage_Checkout_CartController?

Comment: No, there is no code outside of core that uses Mage_Checkout_CartController

Comment: Debut Mage_Checkout_CartController::add method, you will get some clue